# Mapbox mapview language

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

we have integrated Mapbox for our website. But our website is in German and the map of Mapbox is displayed in English. We could not figure out, how to change the language of the map display. Even with checking it here: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/overview/

Do you have an idea how to change the display language of the map in a contact page of the website for example?

Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You can change the language in the Mapbox style editor. Have a read here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/change-language/

Comment: Hi Philipp, thank you for your quick answer. Sadly, it did not help.

I realized that on the wordpress site, we use the plugin "WP Mapbox GL JS Maps" - there we have access via the token to our mapbox.com account. I dont see any effect there, when changing the language according to docs.mapbox.com.

do you have any other idea?